What is a Freely vibrating stationary wave?
My textbook says "Stationary waves that vibrate freely...."
What does vibrate freely mean here?
Does it mean a stationary wave that vibrates in a vacuum?

What is the textbook?

Possibly Stationary waves that vibrate freely do not transfer energy to their surroundings?

@JohnRennie The textbook is the AQA A level Physics textbook written by Jim Breithaupt and published by Oxford University Press

@SPaul Please include all relevant sections. Your question is not self-contained.
